# How to add a computed column using data from different tables?

Tags: sql

I keep getting error messages for trying to compute `TotalAmount` as a multiple of `unitPrice` and `orderQty` which are all in different tables.

```
CREATE DATABASE SalesDB
GO

USE SalesDB
GO

CREATE TABLE Customer 
(
    CustomerID varchar(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    FirstName char(50) NOT NULL,
    LastName char(50) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE Product 
(
    ProductID varchar(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ProductName char(50) NOT NULL,
    UnitPrice decimal NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE SalesOrder 
(
    SalesOrderID varchar(5) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    CustomerID varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    OrderDate date DEFAULT GETDATE() NOT NULL,
    TotalAmount decimal AS Product.UnitPrice * SalesOrderDetail.OrderQty 
)
GO

CREATE TABLE SalesOrderDetail 
(
    SalesOrderID varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    SalesOrderDetailID varchar(6) NOT NULL,
    OrderQty int NOT NULL,
    ProductID varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_SalesOrderDetail PRIMARY KEY (SalesOrderID, SalesOrderDetailID)
)
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using.

Comment: On a side note: I suggest you use underlines to get your names readable. SQL is generally not a case sensitive language, so SalesOrderDetail is the same as salesorderdetail or SALESORDERDETAIL. It is common to write table and column names in lower case, so some formatting tool may get you salesorderdetail. sales_order_detail would be more readable than that.

Comment: As set up, you can have many SalesOrderDetail for the same Product and SalesOrder. A better primary key might be (SalesOrderID, ProductID).

Comment: ... and if you want to stick with SalesOrderDetailID, then you can make this the primary key, but still add a unique constraint on (SalesOrderID, ProductID).

Answer (score 1):

A computed column gets its value from other columns in the same table row.

What you can do is create a a view instead:

```
CREATE VIEW sales_order_complete AS
(
  SELECT
    so.*,
    (
      SELECT SUM(p.unitprice * sod.orderqty)
      FROM salesorderdetail sod
      JOIN product p ON p.productid = sod.productid
      WHERE sod.salesorderid = so.salesorderid
    ) AS totalamount
  FROM salesorder so
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The database will not do the join for you (and you don't declare your foreign keys so how could it?) [Make a view instead](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_ref_create_view.asp).

```
create view SalesOrderAmount as (
  select
    SalesOrder.*,
    Product.UnitPrice * SalesOrderDetail.OrderQty as TotalAmount
  from SalesOrder
  join SalesOrderDetail on SalesOrder.SalesOrderID = SalesOrderDetail.SalesOrderID
  join Product on SalesOrderDetail.ProductID = Product.ProductID
)
```

Note that you need to tell your UnitPrice how many digits to store like decimal(8,2) else it might only store the integer and truncate the rest.

[Try it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=166b16feef3cad893630b7d01d68b547)

---

There's a number of problems with the schema.

1. Declare all foreign keys.
2. Don't hard code business rules into the schema like 50 characters for names. Those rules will change. Enforce them in the application layer or as a constraint.
3. Don't use char, it's a waste of space. Use varchar or text.
4. Avoid varchar primary keys, they're slow, large and cannot be autogenerated.

   - If you need a special character ID for your business, make it a separate column.
5. Avoid compound primary keys, they're complicated and hard to join with.

   - Make a unique constraint instead.
6. Don't prefix fields with the name of the table, its redundant. Fully qualify the columns as needed.
7. Decimal needs to be given precision and scale.

For example...

```
CREATE TABLE Customer 
(
    -- This is the SQL standard way to do an autogenerated primary key.
    -- Your database may be different.
    id int generated always as identity,

    -- If your business rules require a character ID, make it a unique column.
    LocalID varchar(5) not null,
    constraint Unique_CustomerLocalID unique (LocalID)

    -- varchar only uses as much storage as necessary for each row.
    -- Enforce business limits in the application (or possibly a check constraint).
    -- This avoids having to change the schema because the rules changed.
    FirstName varchar(255) not null,
    LastName varchar(255) not null
)

CREATE TABLE Product 
(
    ID int generated always as identity,

    -- Use varchar. Don't put business rules into the schema.
    Name varchar(255) not null,

    -- XXXXXX.YY
    UnitPrice decimal(8,2) not null
)

CREATE TABLE SalesOrder 
(
    ID int generated always as identity,
    CustomerID int not null,
    constraint FK_SalesOrderCustomer foreign key (CustomerID) references Customer(id),

    -- Probably should be a timestamp. It can always be turned into a date.
    ordered_at timestamp default gettimestamp() not null
)

CREATE TABLE SalesOrderDetail 
(
    SalesOrderID int not null,
    constraint FK_SalesOrderDetailSalesOrder foreign key (SalesOrderID) references SalesOrder(ID)

    ProductID int not null,
    constraint FK_SalesOrderDetailProduct foreign key (ProductID) references Product(ID)

    -- This avoids having an order with the same product multiple times.
    -- Its unclear if this table needs a primary key. If so, make a
    -- normal integer id, not a compound one.
    constraint unique_SalesOrderDetail unique (SalesOrderID, ProductID)

    OrderQty int NOT NULL
)
```